# FileReader API error while using jsmediatags

Tags: javascript, filereader

While using JSMediaTags, the onError event handler for the jsmediatags.open method receives an error object with properties:

```
type = "fileReader"

info = "Offset 0 hasn't been loaded yet"
```

See pseudo-code below.

The exact text of the error is not in the JSMediaTags file, leading me to believe that the error is being generated by the browser, but I am unable to find insight into what the specific problem is.

I'm running this on my local workstation, with a Windows 7 OS running IIS.  I've tested in Chrome v 61, and Firefox v 55.  Same error in both.

As you can see, I'm trying to first send the file object (as a file) into the jsmediatags.read function.  This results in the error detailed above.

I've commented out the code where, instead of the file object, I try sending in 1.) the complete local path to the file, 2.) the result of createObjectURL on the file object, as well as 3.) the file object's name property.  These last 3 do not result in either an onSuccess or onError event being fired.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tagreader/jsmediatags.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="fileinput" onchange="window.handleLocalFiles(this.files)">

<script>

var gobjFileTags = null;

function handleLocalFiles(argFiles){
    if (argFiles && (argFiles.length > 0)){
        testTagReader(argFiles[0]);
    }
}

function testTagReader(objFile){
var objTagReader = null;

var strURL = "";
var strFileName = "";
var strLocalPath = "";

    objTagReader = window.jsmediatags;

    objTagReader.read(objFile, {
        onSuccess: function(tag){
            window.gobjFileTags = tag;
            window.readFileTags();
        },
        onError: function(objError){
            window.alert("objTagReader Error - type: " + objError.type + ", info: " + objError.info);
        }
    });
}

function readFileTags(){
    window.alert("readFileTags called");
}
```

Comment: I'v just got this error too. I'll open an issue on jsmediatags github.